# About Lenovo System Interface Foundation

Tags: laptop

I have Lenovo a V510-15IKB.
After clean installation of Windows, I removed System Interface Foundation V2 from Device Manager and then downloaded and installed the latest version of SIF. I think the installation completed successfully after a restart. The problem is that I don't see System Interface Foundation at the start menu or at delete a program (in the control panel) as I used to, before the clean install when I had Windows 1909. But I see lenovoimcontroller.exe running on the task manager. I'm concerned if installation completed succesfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, System Interface Foundation no longer exists in Programs and Features (at least not on either of my two Lenovo ThinkPads here).

Second, SIF is important for the proper operation of Lenovo Modern IM Controller. Lenovo IM Controller is important and should run. SIF owns it in the sense that fixing Lenovo IM Controller (if it needs repair) is to uninstall SIF, restart and reinstall SIF again. SIF owns more than IM Controller and is part of Vantage, for example.

You can check that SIF is installed by looking in Device Manager. The Driver tab shows you what driver is installed. See the screen shot below. If you have a question, you can uninstall SIF (Device Manager), restart and reinstall SIF by executing the download file from Lenovo.

[image]

Comment: I have it as well! Just wanted to make sure it's not on "Programs and Features" anymore. That's why I thought it does not install. Thank you!